# Why is the size of the below class is 8

Tags: c++

The size of below class as i think it should be 6 but the compiler show it's 8.

Anybody please explain why it is 8 instaed 6.
Thanks

```
class Size{
    int a;
    char b;
    char c;
};
```

Comment: Padding bytes will be added to optimize memory access time. - https://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-structure-padding/

Comment: fwiw nothing but common sense forbids the size of this struct to be eg 42.

Comment: It depends on what ISA (Instruction Set Architecture) you are developing on. I imagine you are using x86-64? If so, then I believe an int occupies 4 bytes, while characters occupy 1 byte. So as things stand, you are correct, the class would seemingly have 6 bytes total in size, but the compiler will automatically pad another 2 bytes to make the size of the class 8 bytes to optimize for cache transfers, among other things.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Alignment

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.